# QT multiple project configuration

Tags: c++, qt, configuration

New to QT but can't see how I can't switch between debug and release configurations across multiple projects.

I have a session with 20+ projects in it, and switching between 4 configurations means going into each one and selecting a different config, which is just a different flag passed to the makefile. This is far too time consuming, is there a quicker way?

Answer (score 3):

You can make a `Subdirs` project and add your subprojects to its `.pro` file :

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

CONFIG += ordered

SUBDIRS += \
    project1 \
    project2 \
    project3 \
    ...
```

Here the project directories should be added in the `Subdirs` project directory alongside its `.pro` file. Notice that the name of the .pro file of the subprojects should be the same as it's folder name. This way the subprojects are detected and listed in the Projects pane automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new project like `foobar.pro`:

```
TARGET = foobar
TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS += ../foo \
           ../bar
```

This will enable you to compile foo.pro and bar.pro on release/debug mode with one command.

Comment: This looks like it might work. Perhaps I shouldn't have said project. Do I need to create a .pro for each of these 'projects'? I have a .config .files .includes .creator and a makefile in each project.

Comment: I guess `qmake` can automatically create the .pro for the other projects. It won't be too long to test if your other makefiles aren't too complicated. If they are you'll have to tweak the generated `.pro` or mix the use of makefiles with the `.pro`. Seems do-able after some googling but I never tried it myself.